# Why converting a char array to string creates a nil string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf-8, nsstring, char

Heres what my array of chars returns:

```
 char *methodChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
```

> (char *) methodChars = 0x090f5e00 "Start cooking pasta in a large pan of boiling water.\xa0 Meanwhile, spray a large pan with oil and heat.\xa0\xa0 Add the onion and celery and cook over medium heat for 3 minutes or until soft.\xa0 Stir in the corn kernels.\xa0 Put the cornflour into a small bowl and gradually add 80 ml (1/3 cup) milk, stirring until smooth.\xa0 Add the remaining milk and the stock to the pan then gradually add the cornflour mixture, stirring constantly.\xa0 Keep stirring until the sauce boils and thickens.\xa0 Remove from heat and stir in the cheese until melted.\xa0 When the pasta is al dente, drain and add with the tuna to the pan.\xa0 Stir to combine, and serve immediately."

Heres where I convert it and this is what I get:

```
NSString *method = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:methodChars];
```

This is what I get from method:

> nil

Can someone explain why, and how I fix this please?

This code works for some cases when the methodChars dont contain `\xa0` and just have a space instead. Can anyone explain why this might be a reason?

Comment: @DietrichEpp, the debugger output he shared had enough information to identify the problem. `methodChars != NULL`, `method == nil`, value of `methodChars`.  The other code is meaningless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string is not encoded in UTF-8: it includes the byte `\xa0`. If the string was supposed to contain the U+00A0 non-breaking space character it should have been encoded as `\xc2\xa0`.

You can create the string with an encoding where `\xa0` maps to a valid character, for example:

```
NSString *method = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:methodChars encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Would it be possible for me to strip out those characters rather than changing the encoding type? Something similar to this that would work with an array of chars? [nameChars stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u00a0" withString:@" "];

Comment: It would, but why bother? If the non-breaking space comes out as invalid UTF-8, sooner or later something else will, too, unless you ensure that you always store proper UTF-8 strings in the database.